# Badly placed ()'s when running selected text in VS Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

I ran a console.log statement in the VS Code terminal (highlighted and selected "run selected text.") The terminal showed 'Badly placed ()'s' rather than the expected output. Why might this happen? Please let me know what other information you need from me to answer this question. This happens when I run any statement at all in the terminal.

Comment: there is NO terminal that understands JavaScript.

Comment: The shells you likely have available (bash, CMD, PowerShell... whatever) aren't a JavaScript interpreter. You need something like Node.js.